# trying to enable a checkbox in checkboxlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

i am trying to enable a checkbox in my checkboxlist. The only thing that does not work in my solution is to remove the disabled attribute from the span in IE9, it works in FF:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function enablebut() {
            $('#CheckBoxList1_0').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#CheckBoxList1_0').closest('span').removeAttr('disabled');

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button onclick="enablebut();">enable</button>
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" Enabled='false' runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="een"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="twee"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `type="button"` attribute to prevent the submit (postback).

```
 <button type="button" onclick="enablebut();">enable</button>
```

Or

```
<input type="button"  onclick="enablebut();" value="enable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of passing a function through javascript, you should write the following code inside document.ready function since you are using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#CheckBoxList1_0').attr('disabled','');
    })
```

EDIT: with whole page code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#CheckBoxList1_0').attr('disabled','');
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <button type="button">enable</button>
    <div>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" Enabled='false' runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="een"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="twee"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it does work i have tested the same in IE 7,8,9 Chrome, Mozilla, 3.5 to 8.0 versions

Answer (score 0):

Its not wroking in IE8, here is the below code

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkList" runat="server" Enabled="false" >
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>

                        </asp:CheckBoxList>


            <asp:Button ID="btnFoo" runat="server" Text="Test" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $('#<% = btnFoo.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                        //var targetValue = 2;
                        var items = $('#<% = chkList.ClientID %> input:checkbox');
                        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                //alert(i);
                            //if (items[i].value == targetValue) {
                            items[i].checked = true;

                               // break;
                            //}
                        }
```

$('#<%= chkList.ClientID %> input:checkbox').removeAttr('disabled');                            return false;
                        })
                    });